# 100+ errors from wingdi.h when building

Tags: c++

So I am making a game, an ASCII dungeon explorer and I had a plan to get the window size and scale the display the inventory beside the dungeon. I went on google to find a function that would return the window size so I can print the inv on the side... The parts that are commented out is the code that I found and so I tried to put it in my main.cpp just to try it out. I planned to use other functions that I found to get the max size of the window and to set the size. This code that I pasted into my code was giving me loads of errors when I went to run the game, somewhere around 180 errors from a header file called wingdi.h. I googled a bit more and found people changing some definitions in the project properties which I tried and it gave me about 130 errors from different headers included in . Someone said that one of the variables is already declared in windows.h and the person that asked that question should change it to something else so I changed csbi to my_csbi, both didn't work. Some people also said it was a problem with the code so I decided to just leave it for now, and go back to my old code and do something else for now (I was getting frustrated, lol). I commented it all out, hoping to come back to it later. When I tried to run my game with all of that code gone, it gave me the same errors. Do I have to reinstall Visual Studio 2015? Starting my code from scratch or changing some definitions?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    //#include <Windows.h>
    #include "GameSystem.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        //int x = 0;
        //int y = 0;

        //CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO my_csbi;
        //GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &my_csbi);

        //x = my_csbi.srWindow.Right -my_csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
        //y = my_csbi.srWindow.Bottom -my_csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;

        //printf("columns: %d\n", x);
        //printf("rows: %d\n", y);

        GameSystem gameSystem("level1.txt");

        gameSystem.playGame();

        printf("Enter any key to exit...\n");
        int tmp;
        cin >> tmp;
        return 0;
    }
```

I am fairly new to programming so I'm sorry if my question is stupid or "simple" and if that offended you in some shape or form. :)

Thanks, Bulky.

EDIT: All the "solutions" others got didn't work for me and I decided to ask this because after I commented out all that code, my old code didn't even run (it was perfect before).

Comment: Try including it after windows.h, not before.

Comment: Start with the first error, and ignore the rest - many of them will be either the same problem, or cconsequential ones.  1. Please post the first 5 errors.  2. post the #includes of "GameSystem.h"

Comment: By "try including", do you mean include wingdi.h? I tried after, before and both are the same.

http://prntscr.com/bh4mma Here is a screenshot of the first 5 errors and my setup right now.
http://prntscr.com/bh4nxp This is my GameSystem.h

Comment: Ben's Turorials that you are watching, remain the best ones out there on Youtube, but if you are a newbie, you have to be very patient. No experimenting for noobs.The 25th vid explains window handling stuff throughly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You never include `<WinGdi.h>` directly. You *always* include `<Windows.h>`, which pulls in the required headers implicitly.
2. The GDI functions (from `<WinGdi.h>`) aren't going to do you any good if you are writing a console application. The `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo` function is probably what you want to be using, but it is not a GDI function. It is a kernel function. Again, although it is technically declared in `<WinCon.h>`, you are not supposed to include that header directly. Just include `<Windows.h>`.

The following code works fine for me
(other than the fact that `std::cin` doesn't actually work for "enter any key to exit..."):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
   GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);

   int x = csbi.srWindow.Right  - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
   int y = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top  + 1;

   printf("columns: %d\n", x);
   printf("rows: %d\n", y);


   printf("Enter any key to exit...\n");
   int tmp;
   cin >> tmp;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
columns: 90
rows: 33
Enter any key to exit...
```

If it does not work for you, one of the following must be true:

<strike>1. The problem resides in `"GameSystem.h"`, which you have not shown us.</strike>
(It is fine—in the future, please post code as text, not pictures.)

2. You have created the wrong type of project (recreate a new project using the Win32 Console Application template).

3. There is something wrong with your installation of Visual Studio (try reinstalling).

Comment: That's what I though so the first time I tried using that, I just included <windows.h>.
I used an empty project instead of a Win32 Console Application.
I'm using the cin >> tmp; instead of a system("PAUSE"); It's not supposed to really do anything apart from keeping the console up after the program is done.

Comment: I watched tutorials from MakingGameswithBen and he always used the empty project so I thought there isn't any difference. And yeah, sorry about the pictures. I didn't have a good way of sending the errors without re-writing them so I went for the screenshots XD

Comment: I have no idea what Ben is doing in his videos, but if you don't really understand the project and compiler settings, you are much better off going with a standard template. It will get everything set up correctly, preventing any strange problems, like failing to specify the required LIB files, having the wrong subsystem set, etc. @bulky

Comment: So I made a brand new project that was a Win32 Console Application and it worked flawlessly, there is only one problem. It made like 4 files and I don't have a clue how to use the Win32... template. Can I just delete the files it made and treat it like an empty project or would that cause errors now or later? I only ever used empty project to make very simple things. xd Could I add a GUI to that Win32 console app project later using OpenGL and GLEW or would I have to make a new project and copy the code? @Cody Gray

Comment: @bulky The only problem you'll have is that, by default, it turns on precompiled headers. Which isn't really a bad thing, because it can speed up compile times by ensuring that system header files that you never change only have to be compiled once, not each time you rebuild. You can [turn those off, if you want](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37815078/366904) (see the "bonus" section), or just leave them on and include stuff like `<iostream>` and `<Windows.h>` there, instead of each in of your source files. Otherwise, yes, everything in the template can be deleted from the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Adding a GUI later is certainly possible. The template doesn't lock you into anything, it just sets certain project settings by default. If you know what you are doing, you can tweak them however you desire. If you switch to OpenGL, you will no longer want a console application, so you'll have to either change the subsystem in the project properties, or create a new project with a different template. Hopefully by the time that time comes, you'll understand more about the Visual Studio build system. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Cody Gray. This helped me out a lot! :)

Comment: I googled and found that I can chance an empty project to a Win32 console app in the Properties, Linker, System and Subsystem but it didn't work. I'm guessing I have to copy paste everything over, right?

Comment: @bulky Yes, that should work. I looked at your screenshot, but I can't see all of the errors. Most importantly, I can't see the errors at the *top* of the list. The ones further down don't tell me much, they're just the same type of thing repeated over and over. So I have no idea what is wrong with your current project. Anyway, you don't have to copy and paste everything. You can drag the existing files over into the new project folder. Or you can copy and paste. Whatever is easier.

Comment: I deleted the files it created and it gave me errors so I made a new project, where I plan to bring my code to but do I have to use the stdafx.h / .cpp or targetver.h for anything or can I continue to make my game like I did before?

Comment: @bulky StdAfx.h/.cpp implements the precompiled header that I was talking about. TargetVer.h just defines what version of Windows you support. This controls which API functions are available for you to call. It is in a separate file so that it will work with the resource compiler. You don't need resources in a console application, so you can delete that. You should consider getting a book that teaches you how to write code in Visual Studio. It is very hard to get up to speed trying to figure it all out on your own.

Comment: That's why I was watching Ben. I am just going to give up with this window size stuff tho, It's getting to complicated for such a small thing and I keep getting different errors like "unexpected end of file while looking for precomplied header. Did you forget to include stdafx.h in your source"? At one point I managed to get 1300+ errors so I will just leave it hahah. I am still at a learning stage of C++ and I thought an ASCII Dungeon Explorer would be a nice challenge. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for all the help. :3 @Cody Gray